# regex suggestion

Tags: grep, regular-expression

```
echo "223255/12345678                    " | grep '[0-9a-zA-Z/\-\?:\(\)\.,"\+]{1,34}'
```

According to the regex, it can have any of `0-9 a-z A-Z  / - ? : (  ) . , " +` of upto 34 chars in any order. Am I right?

In that case, why is it not printing the echoed value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `egrep` or pass the `-E` flag to `grep`:

```
echo "223255/12345678                    " | egrep '[0-9a-zA-Z/\-\?:\(\)\.,"\+]{1,34}'
```

or

```
echo "223255/12345678                    " | grep -E '[0-9a-zA-Z/\-\?:\(\)\.,"\+]{1,34}'
```

Comment: That would still match on `x@`, `\\ `, possibly `é` and not `-`

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code:

- Inside `[...]`, the only special characters are `-` and `]` (though there's also `[:` which introduces character classes) and the way to escape them is not with `\`, but for `-` by making it the first or last character in the list (`[-...]` or `[...-]`) and for `]` by making it the first (`[]...]`). Above, `\-\` means any character in the range `\` to `\`, that is it includes `\`, but not `-`. So you'd need `[-0-9a-zA-Z/?:().,"+]`.
- Beware that ranges like `a-z` and `A-Z` are locale-dependant (like may include things like é, ŝ...) and may also include multibyte characters. If you only want to include ASCII characters in those ranges, you should fix the locale to C: `... | LC_ALL=C grep ...`
- `{x,y}` is an extended regular expression operator (as supported by `grep -E`). The corresponding basic regular expression (as supported by `grep`) operator is `\{x,y\}`. So `LC_ALL=C grep '[-0-9a-zA-Z/?:().,"+]\{1,34\}'`
- in `grep pattern`, `grep` checks if `pattern` matches anywhere **inside** each line of input. If you want it to match the *whole line*, you need the `-x` option (for *exact*) or anchor the pattern at the start and end with the `^` and `$` regexp operators. `grep -E 'x{1,34}'` is the same as `grep x`, because a line that contains any sequence of 1 to 34 `x` also contains one `x` and a line that contains an `x` contains a sequence of 1 `x` so matches the `x{1,34}` regexp.
- Assuming you're doing `echo "$var" | grep the-pattern`, beware that it's not reliable, because some `echo` for instance would turn `-neen` into an empty string while others would turn `\n` into a newline character for instance. Also note that `grep` matches on every line of the input, not on the whole input, so your check might not be valid if `$var` may contain newline characters. Best would be to use `expr` instead or the `[[ $var =~ pattern ]]` operator of ksh93, zsh or bash.

To sum up, if you want to check that `$var` is made of 1 to 34 of those ASCII characters, you should write it:

```
if LC_ALL=C expr "x$var" : 'x[-0-9a-zA-Z/?:().,"+]\{1,34\}$' > /dev/null; then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

(`expr` anchors the pattern to the start implicitly as if there was a `^` regexp operator)

Comment: This was perhaps a bit more than the OP meant to ask for, but it's a great reference! I'm keeping this for when I'm hitting my head against the desk with some weird regex problem I just can't figure out. (It's a shame one cannot favorite answers.)

Comment: Thank you for taking time in suggesting solutions for problems in my regex.

Answer (score 0):

maybe escape the `/` character.....what is the `(\)` used for?  But Seems like since you are within single quotes you don't have to escape everything you put in there.

My suggestion to debug is to remove some of the characters and see what is wrong with your pattern.